# C++ program automatically rounding off double values except the first value in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, double, overloading

I am using this code for the function overloading using C++ to sort a double and an integer array.

```
 #include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void sort(int arr[],int n)
{
    int i,j,key;
    for(j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        key=arr[j];
        i=j-1;
        while((i>=0)&&(arr[i]>key))
        {
            arr[i+1]=arr[i];
            i--;
        }
        arr[i+1]=key;
    }
    cout<<"Sorted integer array is \n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}

void sort(double arr[],int n)
{

    int i,j,key;
    for(j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        key=arr[j];
        i=j-1;
        while((i>=0)&&(arr[i]>key))
        {
            arr[i+1]=arr[i];
            i--;
        }
        arr[i+1]=key;
    }
    cout<<"Sorted double array is \n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the array \n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter the values for the integer function \n";
    int a[n];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    double b[n];
    cout<<"Enter the values for the double array \n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>b[i];
    }
    sort(a,n);
    sort(b,n);
}
```

In the answer it rounds off the values of the double values except the first entry into the double array. Is there any type casting step which I am missing or any other flaw in the code?

Comment: `VLA`s are not `c++` standard, why wont you use `std::array` / `std::vector`

Comment: I suggest you read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: You are declaring `int a[n];` arrays with non constant number `n`

Comment: `key` should be a double in your double sort function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It was not due to that. I was mistakingly using int key instead of double key. That was causing the type casting as i asked in the question if I was missing any such step.

Comment: @Matt Thank You. It works now.

Comment: I know, but you still should not include that header file!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are **irrevocably** cutting off an floating part of `double` if you save it to `int` variable.

```
int key;
key=arr[j];
```

Thats why are you getting wrong results.

Declare `key` as `double` and it works.

---

Also `VLA`s (variable length arrays) are not standart `C++`.

Here are some other variants

- `std::array`
- `std::vector`
- use `new` & `delete`

Comment: This fixes the immediate issue, but also take a look at some of the comments about variable length arrays, and why you really shouldn't be using them.

Comment: I meant it more for OP than you :)

Comment: _"Also VLAs (variable length arrays) are not standart C++ you shouldn't use them._" I disagree with the last part: it is up to OP to know on what arch their code is going to be compiled and eventually decide whether or not they want to use a GNU extension.

Comment: I wrote it becouse its obvious that OP is beginner and once he could wonder why that code doesnt work on other machines (which havent GNU extension). But i removed it for sure.

Comment: @YSC: Too often if someone is coming to SO to ask a question, they do not know VLAs are nonstandard, and such use is completely unintentional.

Comment: @AndyG I guess you both are right in this context. My bad.